# Subclass NSMutableData in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

I am attempting to create a subclass of `NSMutableData` in Swift called `ServiceProviderData` which will receive two `NSData` instances, do some parsing (oversimplified in my example below) to create a new `NSData` instance that I then want to call `super.init(data: data)` with.

Attempting to implement this using the code below gives me:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** initialization method -initWithBytes:length:copy:deallocator: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class Example.ServiceProviderData: Create a concrete instance!'

I've read that `NSData/NSMutableData` are part of a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) so my question is what methods/properties do I have to implement and how do I do this in swift?

```
class ServiceProviderData: NSMutableData {
    init?(originalResponseData: NSData, identityProviderResponseData: NSData) {

        // Here I'm just appending the two datas but this has 
        // been greatly simplified for demonstrative purposes...

        let data = NSMutableData(data: originalResponseData)
        data.appendData(identityProviderResponseData)

        super.init(data: data)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need an NSMutableData subclass for this? Couldn't you do it in an extension or a separate class?

Comment: @e1985 I could but now my curiosity has taken over so I'm interested to see how one would implement it

Comment: Ok, the answer below about subclassing a class cluster may be helpful them. I just wanted to point out that subclassing in this situation is not a good idea, even if NSMutableData wouldn't be a class cluster.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't think there is any good reason to do this

You should just have class WRAP a data object IMHO

## BUT

about class clusters:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

A new class that you create within a class cluster must:

- Be a subclass of the cluster’s abstract superclass
- Declare its own storage
- Override all initializer methods of the superclass
- Override the superclass’s primitive methods (described below)

### for NSData the primitive methods are `bytes` and `length`